# Laravel Eloquent statement returns back more records than I expect

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I would like to return back each thread only 1 time, however I keep getting errors returned back saying I have to have additional items in the groupBy clause.  This makes it so that some threads display more than once (once for the first time it is posted, then again if I have voted on it).  How can I limit it to 1 time with it preferring the time where threads_users.user_id is filled.

```
$threads = Thread::leftjoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'threads.user_id')
    ->leftjoin('users as poster','poster.id', '=', 'threads.user_id')
    ->leftjoin('lewps_threads', 'lewps_threads.thread_id','=','threads.id')
    ->leftjoin('threads_users', 'threads_users.thread_id','=','threads.id')
    ->where('threads.id', $id)
    ->wherein('threads_users.user_id', array(null, $users->id))
    ->groupBy(array('threads.id', 'users.username','threads_users.boosts'))
    ->get(array('threads.*','users.username','threads_users.boosts'));
```

Comment: I don't know how familiar you are with SQL in general, but I suggest you install the [Laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar), so you can see what query the above returns

Answer (score 0):

To get out what is going on and what query is executed under the hood you can put this after executing query:

```
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

To return only 1 raw you can add this to your code:

```
->take(1)->get();
```

So this would be something like that:

```
$threads = Thread::leftjoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'threads.user_id')
    ->leftjoin('users as poster','poster.id', '=', 'threads.user_id')
    ->leftjoin('lewps_threads', 'lewps_threads.thread_id','=','threads.id')
    ->leftjoin('threads_users', 'threads_users.thread_id','=','threads.id')
    ->where('threads.id', $id)
    ->wherein('threads_users.user_id', array(null, $users->id))
    ->groupBy(array('threads.id', 'users.username','threads_users.boosts'))
    ->take(1)
    ->get(array('threads.id','users.username','threads_users.boosts'));
```

NOTE that I  have changed 'threads.*' to 'threads.id' in your get part ... tou have to sync your select list with your group by calusule.

Comment: This is close, but the problem is that take(1) wouldn't necessarily take the one that contains a threads_users.user_id (if it existed).